# "You're opening application XYZ for the first time" warning never goes away

Tags: terminal, applications

Every single time I try to open a PDF with Sioyek from terminal (using `open` command) I get this annoying warning:

[image]

Is there anyway to get rid of this? Ideally I don't want macOS to ever warn me about this.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, by opening it from Terminal, you're bypassing the Quarantine requirement.

Try opening the app once from Finder, by right click, Open - then confirm the dialog. Then test Terminal again.